# IPSec Tunnel via Shared band using local IP instead of external

Tags: networking, vpn, ip, remote-desktop, ipsec

We have recently moved onto Shared Band which is causing us some issues. We have a direct Ip Address Mapping which maps our External Address down to our internal address set on the router (which passes all protocols / ports down to our local IP - This is how shared band works) like so:

`1.1.1.1 -> 192.168.2.50`

The problem we are facing is when we create an IPsec tunnel from the router it is passing the `192.168.2.50` address instead of the external one (1.1.1.1) through the tunnel when trying to access remote desktop connections. We are using a Vigor 2820 firewall and the IPSec tunnel is a LAN to LAN setup. I have tried specifying the "WAN IP" against the IPSec connection but this doesn't seem to make any difference.

The I.T company at the other end can only see us create the tunnel and then try to connect to an RDP connection from the internal address but their firewalls are only set up to allow our external IP through.

Any ideas?

Comment: What, exactly, is "Shared Band"?

Comment: A quick google will answer that question. Basically it's a way of having up to 4 internet connections coming through one Router.

Comment: No need to get snarky. This is a relatively unknown, obscure brand name for a technology that is typically referred to as "Multi-WAN Load Balancing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once setting the My WAN IP Field then this should bring the tunnel up ok, as Sharedband is basically performing a static 1:1 NAT, what is the device the other end using?

ErikA, Sharedband is more then Load Balancing as it is true Bonding on the IP Layer.

You also may find this Article useful:
http://support.sharedband.com/kb/kb16/Configuring+Draytek+VPNs+to+work+with+Sharedband

Comment: We were setting this field but it seems because the Routers Firmware was out of date something was broken. I performed a firmware upgrade last night and now the options are working correctly. Thanks for your help.